# How to open CSV file in separate window

Tags: javascript, php, csv

I have two buttons `CreateFile`,`GetFile`. When I click on `CreateFile` button, the csv file created with proper data in a separate folder. My question is how to display created csv file in a separate window when I click on the `GetFile` button.

This is my sample code:

```
$filePath='orderFile.csv';
$fileName='order/'.$filePath;
```

In the variable `$fileName` gets correct path name
How to display this file in separate window when I click on the `GetFile` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PHP is a server side language you cannot directly open a new tab in the users browser. What you can do is print a few lines of JavaScript.

```
if(isset($_POST['GetFile'])) {
    echo "<script>
        window.open('".$fileName."');
    </script>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Mark Nijboer. I

Answer (score 1):

In javascript you can use `window.open(url)`. You will need to do this when the user clicks the button, or have some javascript run after the post back.